# Flutter class won't get relationships

Tags: flutter

I have a class which have other classes as relationship but I cannot fetch related class data in my screen.

**Code**

```
Future<Will?> getData(token) async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://example.com/api/user/myData'),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json'
      },
    );
    print('2::: ${response.statusCode}'); // 200
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print('2-1::: ${jsonResponse['data']}'); // data exist
      var message = jsonResponse['message'];



      var data = Will.fromJson(jsonResponse['data']); // before adding relationships to my class was working.
      print('2-2::: $data'); // won't execute
      print('3::: ${data.documents.length}'); // won't execute 
      return data;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}
```

`Will class`

```
class Will {
  final String id;
  final String note;
  final User user; // added
  final List<WillDocs> documents; // added
  final List<WillVideos> videos; // added
  final String createdAt;
  final String updatedAt;

  Will({
    required this.id,
    required this.note,
    required this.user, // added
    required this.documents, // added
    required this.videos, // added
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory Will.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Will(
      id: json['id'],
      note: json['note'],
      user: json['user'], // added
      documents: json['documents'], // added
      videos: json['videos'], // added
      createdAt: json['createdAt'],
      updatedAt: json['updatedAt'],
    );
  }
}
```

`WillDoc class` (WillVideo calass is the same as this one...)

```
class WillDocs {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String size;
  final String extention;
  final String createdAt;
  final String updatedAt;

  WillDocs({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.size,
    required this.extention,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory WillDocs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return WillDocs(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      size: json['size'],
      extention: json['extention'],
      createdAt: json['createdAt'],
      updatedAt: json['updatedAt'],
    );
  }
}
```

And here is how my data are returning from server

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "//data",
        "note": "/data",
        "user": {
            //data
        },
        "documents": [
            //data
        ],
        "videos": [], // currently empty
        "createdAt": "06-01-2021 04:06 AM",
        "updatedAt": "06-01-2021 05:06 AM"
    },
    "message": "Data is ready."
}
```

**Update**

Here is my console that shows code after line `var data = Will.fromJson(jsonResponse['data']);` will not execute

[image: one]

Comment: In your data, the field "userId" is not found ? Have you checked it ?

Comment: that was changed with `final User user;` (i've already removed it yet issue exist)

Comment: Not Executing means ? what happening ? Error occurring or shows empty data ?

Comment: Means my code stop at this line `var data = Will.fromJson(jsonResponse['data']);`  and nothing else will be printed in console...

Comment: @NaveenAvidi if I remove this 3 lines from my class its working just fine `final User user; // added
  final List<WillDocs> documents; // added
  final List<WillVideos> videos; // added`

Comment: Even instance is not printing like instance of Will ? Try changing fields List<WillDocs> and List<WillVideos> to List ! (Only List or List<dynamic> and User to dynamic or Map

Comment: @NaveenAvidi even with only `List` or `List<dynamic>` it does not make any changes

Comment: @NaveenAvidi see my update please

Comment: Being you are having custom classes in Will class, you better to assign that data through WillDocs.fromJSON and WillVidoe.fromJSON ! Like how you are assigning Will data

Comment: @NaveenAvidi meaning?

Comment: Fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67882352/flutter-class-wont-get-relationships#comment119986528_67883032)

Answer (score 0):

```
factory Will.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Will(
  id: json['id'],
  note: json['note'],
  user: User.fromJSON(json['user']),
  documents: WillDocs.fromJson(json['documents']), // added
  videos: WillVideos.fromJson(json['videos']), // added
  createdAt: json['createdAt'],
  updatedAt: json['updatedAt'],
);
```

}

```
//add this in your WillDocs class
List<WillDocs> fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<WillDocs> list =[];
    for (var item in json['documents']){
    list.add(WillDocs(
      //your fields
    );
   )
   return list;
  }

//add this in your WillVidoes class
List<WillVideos> fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   List<WillVideos> list =[];
    for (var item in json['videos']){
    list.add(WillVideos(
      //your fields
    );
   )
   return list;
  }
```

Comment: I think it should use return

Comment: it says `The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.` on `fromJson`

Comment: I updated my answer, are you using same as above when initializing ?

Comment: yes, the error I've mentioned comes from `List<WillDocs> fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {`

Comment: Make sure to return list fromJson methods in WillDocs and WillVideos ?

Comment: I've managed to [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67882352/flutter-class-wont-get-relationships#comment119986528_67883032) now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is some stuff missing in your Will.fromJson function.
You did write the fromJson functions in the other classes, but you are not using them.

EDIT: This example is for if you are using null safety.

```
class Will {
  final String id;
  final String note;
  final User user; // added
  final List<WillDocs?> documents; // added
  final List<WillVideos?> videos; // added
  final String createdAt;
  final String updatedAt;

  Will({
    required this.id,
    required this.note,
    required this.user, // added
    required this.documents, // added
    required this.videos, // added
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory Will.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Will(
      id: json['id'],
      note: json['note'],
      user: User.fromJson(json['user']), // added
      documents: json['documents'] 
        ? WillDocs.fromJson(json['documents']) as List<WillDocs?>
        : <WillDocs?>[], // added
      videos: json['videos'] 
        ? WillVideos.fromJson(json['videos']) as List<WillVideos?>
        : <WillVideos?>[], // added
      createdAt: json['createdAt'],
      updatedAt: json['updatedAt'],
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: in case you are not using null safety:

```
class Will {
      final String id;
      final String note;
      final User user; // added
      final List<WillDocs> documents; // added
      final List<WillVideos> videos; // added
      final String createdAt;
      final String updatedAt;
    
      Will({
        required this.id,
        required this.note,
        required this.user, // added
        required this.documents, // added
        required this.videos, // added
        required this.createdAt,
        required this.updatedAt,
      });
    
      factory Will.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Will(
          id: json['id'],
          note: json['note'],
          user: User.fromJson(json['user']), // added
          documents: json['documents'] 
            ? json['documents'].map((i)=>WillDocs.fromJson(i)).toList()
            : <WillDocs>[], // added
          videos: json['videos'] 
            ? json['videos'].map((i)=>WillVideos.fromJson(i)).toList()
            : <WillVideos>[], // added
          createdAt: json['createdAt'],
          updatedAt: json['updatedAt'],
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: it says `The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<WillDocs>'` for your second code, and for first one says `The argument type 'List<WillDocs>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<WillDocs>'`

Comment: Ill edit my anwser i made a mistake I see

Comment: Adding the questing mark to make it nullable works aswel. Edited that.

Comment: No without question mark errors are gone but still can't get my data in screen (refer to my screenshot)

Comment: You already decode your JSON in line 103. Which meens you cannot decode it anymore. The best way is to add another class which contains the Will. To do the decode in line 103 with a .fromJson function.

Comment: `Will.fromJson(response.body)` result : `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: maybe is best is I just return my API decoded result `jsonResponse['data']` instead of using `fromJson`?!

Comment: Yes you've already decoded it in line 103. There's an ugly fix which is to encode it again en the use will.fromJson(json.encode(jsonResponse['data']) ) but i reccomend my other comment. which i edited.

Comment: If you do not need the other data. Then yes I'd recommend to change that.

Comment: here is what I did and it worked `1` changed my function to void `Future<void>` . `2` in my screen I called my data like this `${snapshot.data!['documents'].length}` now I get my data.

Comment: I don't understand how Future<void> works, it doesn't return a void haha

Comment: TBH I have no idea. I'm extremely newbie in flutter :)